# How to apply an operation on a vector with offsets

Tags: pandas, numpy, offset

Consider the following `pd.DataFrame`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_end = pd.DataFrame([[(0, 3), (4, 5), (6, 12)], [(7, 10), (11, 90), (91, 99)]])
values = np.random.rand(1, 99)
```

The `start_end` is a `pd.DataFrame` of shape `(X, Y)` where each value inside is a tuple of `(start_location, end_location)` in the `values` vector. Another way of saying that the values in a particular cell is a vector of different lengths.

**Question**

If I want to find the mean (for example) of the vector values for each of the cells in the `pd.DataFrame`, how can I do this in a cost effective way?

I managed to achieve this with an [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function, but it's quite slow.

I guess I need to find some way to present it in a `numpy` array and then map it back to the 2d data-frame, but I can't figure out how.

**Notes**

- The distance between start end can varies and outliers can exist.
- The cell start / end is always non-overlapping with the other cells (it will be interest to see if this prerequisite affect speed of solution).

**The generalized problem**

More generally speaking I this as a recurring problem of how to make a 3d array, where one of the dimensions is not of equal length to a 2d matrix via some transformation function (mean, min, etc.)

Comment: What are the sizes of your data?

Comment: Usually it's about 10,000 x 100,000 (the `start_end`) and the vector is about `10,000,000`
If you think - the vector is too small, this is because often the `start_end` has tuples of negative or nan values (i.e. this cell does not contain info in the `values` vector)

Comment: Shouldn't `start_end` be a 2D array of (N,2) shape?

Comment: For each row in `start_end`, are the cells non-overlapping and in increasing order?

Comment: @Divakar I updated the description. Maybe an `(N, 2)` would be the state after one transformation step, as long as it can be mapped back to the 2d matrix of original size.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes. This is actually an important point.

Comment: I modified the example slightly (not changing functionality) to include one case where the distance between start end is an outlier to the rest.

Comment: @Newskooler Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62767256/13636407). It is using `xarray`.

Comment: I've done this thousands of times and I ensure you that, for computing mean in your case, you'll never go as fast as if you precompute cumulative sums. Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Prospective approach

Looking at your sample data :

```
In [64]: start_end
Out[64]: 
         0         1         2
0   (1, 6)    (4, 5)   (6, 12)
1  (7, 10)  (11, 12)  (13, 19)
```

It is indeed non-overlapping for each row, but not across the entire dataset.

Now, we have [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) that gives us ufunc reduction for each slice :

```
ufunc(ar[indices[i]: indices[i + 1]])
```

as long as `indices[i] < indices[i+1]`.

So, with `ufunc(ar, indices)`, we would get :

```
[ufunc(ar[indices[0]: indices[1]]), ufunc(ar[indices[1]: indices[2]]), ..]
```

In our case, for each tuple `(x,y)`, we know `x<y`. With stacked version, we have :

```
[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), ...]
```

If we flatten, it would be :

```
[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, ...]
```

So, we might not have `y1<x2`, but that's okay, because we don't need ufunc reduction for that one and similarly for the pair : `y2,x3`. But that's okay as they could be skipped with a stepsize slicing of the final output.

Thus, we would have :

```
# Inputs : a (1D array), start_end (2D array of shape (N,2))
lens = start_end[:,1]-start_end[:,0]
out = np.add.reduceat(a, start_end.ravel())[::2]/lens
```

`np.add.reduceat()` part gives us the sliced summations. We needed the division by `lens` for the average computations.

Sample run -

```
In [47]: a
Out[47]: 
array([0.49264042, 0.00506412, 0.61419663, 0.77596769, 0.50721381,
       0.76943416, 0.83570173, 0.2085408 , 0.38992344, 0.64348176,
       0.3168665 , 0.78276451, 0.03779647, 0.33456905, 0.93971763,
       0.49663649, 0.4060438 , 0.8711461 , 0.27630025, 0.17129342])

In [48]: start_end
Out[48]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6, 12],
       [ 7, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [13, 19]])

In [49]: [np.mean(a[i:j]) for (i,j) in start_end]
Out[49]: 
[0.30963037472653104,
 0.5072138121177008,
 0.5295464559328862,
 0.41398199978967815,
 0.7827645134019902,
 0.5540688880441684]

In [50]: lens = start_end[:,1]-start_end[:,0]
    ...: out = np.add.reduceat(a, start_end.ravel())[::2]/lens

In [51]: out
Out[51]: 
array([0.30963037, 0.50721381, 0.52954646, 0.413982  , 0.78276451,
       0.55406889])
```

For completeness, referring back to given sample, the conversion steps were :

```
# Given start_end as df and values as a 2D array
start_end = np.vstack(np.concatenate(start_end.values)) 
a = values.ravel()
```

For other ufuncs that have `reduceat` method, we will just replace `np.add.reduceat`

Comment: can you please show the conversion step form the `pd.DataFrame` I have to the `(N, 2)` array? I struggle with this part.

Comment: @Newskooler Added in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you do `values.ravel() `? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Newskooler Well you have `values = np.random.rand(1, 99)`. So its not a vector, but a 2D array. We need a 1D array for processing, hence flattening with `.ravel()`. If that's ineeded a vector (1D), you can skip ravel.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the above code. Because there is no overlap in the values, for each sum it takes, it skips the `end` value. For example - index value `0` and `3` are s skipped in order to compute a mean for the first two values of `out` of `0.3096303747265310` and ` 0.5072138121177008`

Comment: @Newskooler Not sure what you are pointing at. There's no bug. Check again?

Comment: I am double checking again now.

Comment: @Newskooler Note that I changed the first pair to `[ 1,  3]` to bring variety there.

Comment: It's correct, but it's still skipping a value each time. E.g. a[1:3] and a[4:5] will leave a[3] out of the picture. 
That's an easy fix if the user desires it otherwise though. So thanks a lot. 
To be clear you have two solutions: one with the list comprehension and one with `np.add.reduceat`?

Comment: @Newskooler Yeah it's skipping every other summation, because that's how reduceat could be incorporated to solve our problem. The loop based version is the one I thought you already have/easily achieved and you want to skip it for efficiency purpose.

Comment: So if `start_end` where to be with overlapping such as `[1, 3], [3, 4]` etc. ,then it would not be skipping?

Comment: @Newskooler Only way to not skip is when the end of one slice is same as start of the next slice. Then, we can just use `np.add.reduceat(a, start_end[:,0])`.

Answer (score 2):

For computing mean in your case, you'll never go as fast as if you precompute cumulative sums first using [numpy.cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) for instance. Check out the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

R = 1_000
C = 10_000
M = 100

# Generation of test case
start = np.random.randint(0, M-1, (R*C,1))
end = np.random.randint(0, M-1, (R*C,1))
start = np.where(np.logical_and(start>=end, end>1), end-1, start)
end = np.where(np.logical_and(start>=end, start<M-1), start+1, end)
start_end = np.hstack((start, end))

values = np.random.rand(M)

t_start = time.time()
# Basic mean dataframe
lens = start_end[:,1]-start_end[:,0]
mean = np.add.reduceat(values, start_end.ravel())[::2]/lens
print('Timre 1:', time.time()-t_start, 's')

t_start = time.time()
#Cumulative sum
cum_values = np.zeros((values.size+1,))
cum_values[1:] = np.cumsum(values)
# Compute mean dataframe
mean_2 = (cum_values[start_end[:,1]]-cum_values[start_end[:,0]])/(start_end[:,1]-start_end[:,0])
print('Timre 2:', time.time()-t_start, 's')

print('Results are equal!' if np.allclose(mean, mean_2) else 'Results differ!')
print('Norm of the difference:', np.linalg.norm(mean - mean_2))
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
Timre 1: 0.48940515518188477 s
Timre 2: 0.16983389854431152 s
Results are equal!
Norm of the difference: 2.545241707481022e-12
```

The difference in performance gets even worse when `M` increases. For `M=5000` you get:

```
% python3 script.py
Timre 1: 4.5356669425964355 s
Timre 2: 0.1772768497467041 s
Results are equal!
Norm of the difference: 1.0660592585125616e-10
```

Comment: Yes! After computing cumsum with complexity O(N), all the other mean can be computed with O(1). It's very powerful especially when you have to compute rolling window analysis. You can even use this trick to compute standard deviations or correlations in `O(1)`.

Comment: Can be numerically unstable, though.

Comment: You mean if you get an overflow from cumsum ?

Comment: Even before that if your increments are small compared to the running total you can lose a significant number of bits: Example, just to show the principle `a=np.array([2.0**40,1.2345678])` `np.diff(a.cumsum()) yields `array([1.23461914])`.

Comment: You can actually avoid cumsum getting too high by removing the global vector mean value to each element `values---=np.mean(values)` and then add this value to each mean you compute. This will ensure cumsum ending with `0` instead of a big value. Of course it is necessary to have more infos about the dataset to know if this problem will occur. But in terms of computation time it is a skyrocket.